# Converting varchar data type to decimals in SQL Server with stored procedure errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

A `Quantity` column cannot be changed, it should be a `decimal(18,5)`, and an older SSIS package would actually use VB code to do this

```
 Dim q As Decimal
 q = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow(16))
```

However, I am streamlining the process to import flat file into a new staging table

The value that is getting inserted into a database staging table is inserted as `varchar(40)`.

Example of one of the values:

```
0000000191185.18200-
```

I want to convert that on the fly within a SQL Server query to a `decimal(18,5)`  value in order to insert it into another final table.

Is it accurate to say that the conversion from `varchar` to `decimal(18,5)` should yield the value of -191185.18200 ?

I am trying to test casting of this and I get an error in T-SQL

```
select CAST(Quantity AS DECIMAL(18, 5)) 
from [DST].[DstPositionsStagingT]
```

Error is

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

`Quantity` is the column in the table holding the value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard that recognises a trailing `-` to mean "negative".  Sounds like you have a data quality issue, stemming from the fact that the existing process stores numeric values as strings...  Any solution will need to correct the data before acting on it *(such as the answer below that strips out the trailing `-` if it exists.)*

Comment: its common for this 3 trillion dollar in investment financial giant with the mainframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of embedding simple cleaning in the body of the SQL in the hope that it's easier to read.

```
SELECT
  T.SecurityNumber,
  SUM(clean.quantity)                                AS total_quantity,
  SUM(CASE WHEN clean.quantity IS NULL THEN 1 END)   AS failed_conversions,
  MAX(T.Cusip)                                       AS CUSIP
FROM
  [DST].[DstPositionsStagingT]   AS T
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN T.Quantity LIKE '%-'
              THEN - TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5), LEFT(T.Quantity, LEN(T.Quantity) - 1))
              ELSE   TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5),      T.Quantity                      )
         END
)
  AS clean(quantity)
GROUP BY
   T.SecurityNumber
```

Comment: Think you are pretty slick don't you?  Well you are !   :)    thx man

Answer (score 0):

`0000000191185.18200-` is not a valid format to convert to numeric. The valid format for negative value is `-` sign should be on the left. You can shift the sign the left or remove the `-` sign first convert to numeric and then add back

you can use `case when` check for such case and convert accordingly

```
declare @value  varchar(20)

select  @value  = '0000000191185.18200-'

select  case    when    right(@value, 1) = '-'
        then    -convert(decimal(18,2), replace(@value, '-', ''))
        else    convert(decimal(18,2), @value)
        end
```

Comment: Can I do this all inline with other select values?   Example,  I have like 10 values such as  SecurityNumber,  MAX(Cusip) AS CUSIP,

Comment: yes. why not. Just change the `@value` to your column name and repeat the `case` statement for each of your column

Comment: I get cast error and i'm wondering about some odd spaces as there was an article I was reading

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4008/handling-error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeric-in-sql-server/

Comment: This almost worked , but it bombs on Nulls  `CAST(LEFT(Quantity, CHARINDEX('.', Quantity) - 1) + '.' + SUBSTRING(Quantity,(CHARINDEX('.',Quantity)+1),3) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) CastedNumeric`